# Delete only those FTP files that were previously downloaded using file mask in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, ftp, automation

My exact process looks like:

1. download .zip files from FTP
2. extract .zip files into new folder
3. delete local .zip files
4. delete ftp .zip files

I wrote the following script to push it via Windows Tasks daily. What can be an easy way to double check before I delete the files from FTP?
Comparing file names seems complicated in a batch file. Maybe checking the file count?

```
rem write FTP-download file
echo open Server >>ftpDownload.text
echo user >>ftpDownload.text
echo Password >>ftpDownload.text
echo cd /out >>ftpDownload.text
echo lcd c:\DownloadUPS >>ftpDownload.text
echo binary >>ftpDownload.text
echo prompt >>ftpDownload.text
echo mget *.zip >>ftpDownload.text
echo quit >>ftpDownload.text

rem execute ftp file
ftp -s:ftpDownload.text
del ftpDownload.text

cd C:\DownloadUPS
rem create foldername
FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3,4,5 delims=/. " %%a in ('date/T') do set CDATE=%%a%%b%%c%%d
echo %cdate%
md download%cdate%
rem extract .zip
C:\DownloadUPS\7zcommandline\7za.exe x *.zip -ppassword -oc:\DownloadUPS\download%cdate% -y
del *.zip

rem write ftp-delete file
echo open Server >>ftpDelete.text
echo user >>ftpDelete.text
echo Password >>ftpDelete.text
echo cd /out >>ftpDelete.text
echo binary >>ftpDelete.text
echo prompt >>ftpDelete.text
echo mdel *.zip >>ftpDelete.text
echo quit >>ftpDelete.text
ftp -s:ftpDelete.text
del ftpDelete.text
```

Thanks for review, maybe you can help me with batch coding standards also, my skills are pretty basic ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that your question is, how to make sure you delete only those ZIP files that you have successfully downloaded before.

---

Extract the ZIP files in a `for` loop and generate the `del` command explicitly for each file:

```
echo open Server >>ftpDelete.text
echo user >>ftpDelete.text
echo Password >>ftpDelete.text
echo cd /out >>ftpDelete.text
echo binary >>ftpDelete.text

for %%a in (*.zip) do (
  C:\DownloadUPS\7zcommandline\7za.exe x %%a -ppassword -oc:\DownloadUPS\download%cdate% -y
  echo del %%a >>ftpDelete.text
)

echo quit >>ftpDelete.text
ftp -s:ftpDelete.text
del ftpDelete.text
```

---

Or use an FTP client that can transactionally download and delete files by a mask.

For example with [WinSCP FTP client](https://winscp.net/) you can use:

```
winscp.com /command ^
    "open ftp://user:password@server/" ^
    "get -delete /out/*.zip c:\DownloadUPS\*" ^
    "exit" 

cd C:\DownloadUPS
rem Your extract code follows
```

For more details, see a guide to [automating file transfers from FTP server using WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*